# How to get all enum values as an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enums

I have the following enum.

```
enum EstimateItemStatus: Printable {
    case Pending
    case OnHold
    case Done

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Pending: return "Pending"
        case .OnHold: return "On Hold"
        case .Done: return "Done"
        }
    }

    init?(id : Int) {
        switch id {
        case 1:
            self = .Pending
        case 2:
            self = .OnHold
        case 3:
            self = .Done
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get all the raw values as an array of strings (like so `["Pending", "On Hold", "Done"]`).

I added this method to the enum.

```
func toArray() -> [String] {
    var n = 1
    return Array(
        GeneratorOf<EstimateItemStatus> {
            return EstimateItemStatus(id: n++)!.description
        }
    )
}
```

But I'm getting the following error.

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'GeneratorOf' that accepts an argument list of type '(() -> _)'

Is there is an easier, better or more elegant way to do this?

Comment: you can create array like let array : [EstimateItemStatus] = [.Pending, .Onhold, .Done]

Comment: @KristijanDelivuk I want to add this functionality to the enum itself. So I don't have to go and add it everywhere in other places of the codebases if I ever add another value to the enum.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enumerate an enum with String type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007461/how-to-enumerate-an-enum-with-string-type)

Comment: I have an answer you can refer to here http://stackoverflow.com/a/48960126/5372480

Answer (score 244, accepted):

## For Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10) and later

There's a `CaseIterable` protocol:

```
enum EstimateItemStatus: String, CaseIterable {
    case pending = "Pending"
    case onHold = "OnHold"
    case done = "Done"

    init?(id : Int) {
        switch id {
        case 1: self = .pending
        case 2: self = .onHold
        case 3: self = .done
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}

for value in EstimateItemStatus.allCases {
    print(value)
}
```

---

## For Swift < 4.2

No, you can't query an `enum` for what values it contains. See [this article](http://www.swift-studies.com/blog/2014/6/10/enumerating-enums-in-swift). You have to define an array that list all the values you have. Also check out Frank Valbuena's solution in "[How to get all enum values as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952248/how-to-get-all-enum-values-as-an-array/46853256#46853256)".

```
enum EstimateItemStatus: String {
    case Pending = "Pending"
    case OnHold = "OnHold"
    case Done = "Done"

    static let allValues = [Pending, OnHold, Done]

    init?(id : Int) {
        switch id {
        case 1:
            self = .Pending
        case 2:
            self = .OnHold
        case 3:
            self = .Done
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

for value in EstimateItemStatus.allValues {
    print(value)
}
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28341290/8047 including the Swift 3 code.

Comment: Upvoting for the allValues part, but not sure what to feel about an enum being type String but initialized with Int.

Comment: The first link is broken but appears to be at https://exceptionshub.com/how-to-enumerate-an-enum-with-string-type.html now.

Comment: If I want to delete "OnHold" by checking a condition, what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 95):

## Swift 5

Add [CaseIterable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable) protocol to enum:

```
enum EstimateItemStatus: String, CaseIterable {
    case pending = "Pending"
    case onHold = "OnHold"
    case done = "Done"
}
```

Usage:

```
let values: [String] = EstimateItemStatus.allCases.map { $0.rawValue }
//["Pending", "OnHold", "Done"]
```

Comment: +1. Should be the accepted answer post Swift 5. You can also do `static let values: [String] ...` inside the enum to make it nicer.

Answer (score 51):

**Swift 4.2** introduces a new protocol named `CaseIterable`

```
enum Fruit : CaseIterable {
    case apple , apricot , orange, lemon
}
```

that when you conforms to , you can get an array from the `enum` cases like this

```
for fruit in Fruit.allCases {
    print("I like eating \(fruit).")
}
```

Answer (score 23):

```
enum EstimateItemStatus: String, CaseIterable {
  case pending = "Pending"
  case onHold = "OnHold"
  case done = "Done"

  static var statusList: [String] {
    return EstimateItemStatus.allCases.map { $0.rawValue }
  }
}
```

["Pending", "OnHold", "Done"]

Comment: With the shorthand expression, this looks pretty cool though..

Comment: This is what I want! Thanks for the one line code

Answer (score 17):

There's another way that at least is safe at compile time:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case case1
    case case2
    case case3
}

extension MyEnum {
    static var allValues: [MyEnum] {
        var allValues: [MyEnum] = []
        switch (MyEnum.case1) {
        case .case1: allValues.append(.case1); fallthrough
        case .case2: allValues.append(.case2); fallthrough
        case .case3: allValues.append(.case3)
        }
        return allValues
    }
}
```

Notice that this works for any enum type (RawRepresentable or not) and also if you add a new case then you will get a compiler error which is good since will force you to have this up to date.

Comment: Unorthodox, but it works and it warns you if you modify the enum cases. Clever solution!

Comment: I've never seen like this way. It looks very interesting. But I don't understand some of your codes. How can you put MyEnum.case1 to switch condition? and how did you avoid the error `Switch condition evaluates to a constant`?

Answer (score 13):

To get a list for functional purposes, use the expression `EnumName.allCases` which returns an array e.g.

```
EnumName.allCases.map{$0.rawValue}
```

will give you a  list of Strings given that `EnumName: String, CaseIterable`

Note: use `allCases` instead of `AllCases()`.

Answer (score 12):

I found somewhere this code:

```
protocol EnumCollection : Hashable {}


extension EnumCollection {

    static func cases() -> AnySequence<Self> {
        typealias S = Self
        return AnySequence { () -> AnyIterator<S> in
            var raw = 0
            return AnyIterator {
                let current : Self = withUnsafePointer(to: &raw) { $0.withMemoryRebound(to: S.self, capacity: 1) { $0.pointee }
                }
                guard current.hashValue == raw else { return nil }
                raw += 1
                return current
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
enum YourEnum: EnumCollection { //code }

YourEnum.cases()
```

return list of cases from YourEnum

Comment: Seems like a great solution but has quite a few compile errors on Swift 4.

Comment: The "somewhere" may be: https://theswiftdev.com/2017/10/12/swift-enum-all-values/ (among others?). The blogger credits [CoreKit](https://github.com/corekit/corekit).

Comment: This breaks in XCode 10 (regardless of Swift-version) as the hashValue of an enum no longer incremental but random, breaking the mechanism. The new way to do this is to upgrade to Swift 4.2 and use CaseIterable

Answer (score 3):

**Update for Swift 5**

Easiest solution I've found is to use `.allCases` on an enum that extends `CaseIterable`

```
enum EstimateItemStatus: CaseIterable {
    case Pending
    case OnHold
    case Done

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Pending: return "Pending"
        case .OnHold: return "On Hold"
        case .Done: return "Done"
        }
    }

    init?(id : Int) {
        switch id {
        case 1:
            self = .Pending
        case 2:
            self = .OnHold
        case 3:
            self = .Done
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

`.allCases` on any `CaseIterable` enum will return a `Collection` of that element.

```
var myEnumArray = EstimateItemStatus.allCases
```

more info about [CaseIterable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable)

Comment: There is no need to implement description(). Just equate each case to the string eg `case OnHold = "On Hold"` and that becomes the raw value for each.

Comment: @pnizzle I know, it's there because it was in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use

```
enum Status: Int{
    case a
    case b
    case c

}

extension RawRepresentable where Self.RawValue == Int {

    static var values: [Self] {
        var values: [Self] = []
        var index = 1
        while let element = self.init(rawValue: index) {
            values.append(element)
            index += 1
        }
        return values
    }
}


Status.values.forEach { (st) in
    print(st)
}
```

Comment: Nice! After upgrading from Swift 3.2 to 4.1 this was a solution that I used. We originally had AnyItertor<Self> declarations. Your solution was much cleaner and easier to read. thanks!

Comment: One code flaw here though. It misses the first item in the case.  Change var index = 1 to var index = 0

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2

```
// Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007461/how-to-enumerate-an-enum-with-string-type
func iterateEnum<T where T: Hashable, T: RawRepresentable>(_: T.Type) -> AnyGenerator<T> {
    var i = 0
    return AnyGenerator {
        let next = withUnsafePointer(&i) {
            UnsafePointer<T>($0).memory
        }
        if next.hashValue == i {
            i += 1
            return next
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

func arrayEnum<T where T: Hashable, T: RawRepresentable>(type: T.Type) -> [T]{
    return Array(iterateEnum(type))
}
```

To use it:

```
arrayEnum(MyEnumClass.self)
```

Comment: Why would the elements' `hashValue` be `0..n`?

Answer (score 1):

After inspiration from [Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) and hours of try n errors. I finally got this comfortable and beautiful Swift 4 way on Xcode 9.1:

```
protocol EnumSequenceElement: Strideable {
    var rawValue: Int { get }
    init?(rawValue: Int)
}

extension EnumSequenceElement {
    func distance(to other: Self) -> Int {
        return other.rawValue - rawValue
    }

    func advanced(by n: Int) -> Self {
        return Self(rawValue: n + rawValue) ?? self
    }
}

struct EnumSequence<T: EnumSequenceElement>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    typealias Element = T

    var current: Element? = T.init(rawValue: 0)

    mutating func next() -> Element? {
        defer {
            if let current = current {
                self.current = T.init(rawValue: current.rawValue + 1)
            }
        }
        return current
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
enum EstimateItemStatus: Int, EnumSequenceElement, CustomStringConvertible {
    case Pending
    case OnHold
    case Done

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Pending:
            return "Pending"
        case .OnHold:
            return "On Hold"
        case .Done:
            return "Done"
        }
    }
}

for status in EnumSequence<EstimateItemStatus>() {
    print(status)
}
// Or by countable range iteration
for status: EstimateItemStatus in .Pending ... .Done {
    print(status)
}
```

Output:

```
Pending
On Hold
Done
```

Answer (score 1):

Extension on an enum to create allValues.

```
extension RawRepresentable where Self: CaseIterable {
      static var allValues: [Self.RawValue] {
        return self.allCases.map { $0.rawValue}
      }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your enum is incremental and associated with numbers, you can use range of numbers that you map to enum values, like so:

```
// Swift 3
enum EstimateItemStatus: Int {
    case pending = 1,
    onHold
    done
}

let estimateItemStatusValues: [EstimateItemStatus?] = (EstimateItemStatus.pending.rawValue...EstimateItemStatus.done.rawValue).map { EstimateItemStatus(rawValue: $0) }
```

This doesn't quite work with enums associated with strings or anything other than numbers, but it works great if that is the case!