# Multiple enum implementing protocols questions

Tags: swift, enums, protocols

I defined enums as confirming to a protocol Eventable:

```
protocol Eventable {
    var name: String { get }
    static var all: [Eventable] { get }
}

enum MyEnum: String, Eventable {
    case bla = "bla"
    case blu = "blu"

    var name: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }

    static var all: [Eventable] {
        return [
            MyEnum.bla,
            MyEnum.blu
        ]
    }
}
```

I have other enums like MyEnum also under the form:
    enum Bla: String, Eventable {
    }

I have two questions:

1. for the enums having a String data type, I would like to avoid duplicating the generation of the variable name:
   `var name: String`
   I am not sure how to write that in Swift. I tried to play around with the "where" clause but not success. How can I achieve that?
2. when I write my enums and conform to the protocol for that part:
   `static var all: [Eventable] { get }`.
   I would like that for the enum MyEnum, it constrains the variable to:
   `static var all: [MyEnum] { ... }`
   because for now I can put in the returned array any element being an Eventable and it's not what I need.
   Amongst other things, I tried to define a generic constraint in the protocol for it, but I get the following error:

> Protocol 'Eventable' can only be used as a generic constraint because
>   it has Self or associated type requirements

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, you just need to use `Self`:

```
protocol Eventable {
    var name: String { get }
    static var all: [Self] { get }
}
```

`Self`, similar to `self`, just means "the current type".

The first question is a little bit harder because you can't really get all the values of an enum safely. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952248/get-all-enum-values-as-an-array) for more info. The closest I got was:

```
extension Eventable where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String {
    var name: String {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}
```

This means that you can omit the declaration of `name` in `MyEnum`, but not `all`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

For the first question it works like a charm. 
For the second question, I get the error I was mentioning (_Protocol 'Eventable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements_) when trying to use it.

Comment: @Toka If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: I was editing my message when you answered, sorry. I still have the above mentioned problem for the second question. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Toka Did you use my exact code? Or did the error occur somewhere else, not in the extension? Basically, the error says that you can't use `Eventable` as a method parameter or the type of a variable anymore, because it has `Self` in it.

Comment: Yes I used the code your provided. For example I have a function with the following signature in a different object that triggers the error: `func track(event: Eventable)`

Comment: @Toka You can't do that if you use `Self`. Because in the function at compile time, you don't know what type `Self` actually is. So you either don't use `Self`, or rethink about how to redesign your model so as to work around this problem.

Comment: I have tried to find a way in what I'm trying to achieve here to work around this problem with the constraints that I have. I think I'll go with the "not use `Self`" approach. Thank you for your valuable inputs. You helped solve a part of the problem, and that's already much better than how it was before.

Answer (score 1):

For the part of the question we need to extend `Eventable` protocol where `Self` inherits `RawRepresentable`

```
protocol Eventable {
    var name: String { get }
    static var all: [Self] { get }
}

extension Eventable where Self: RawRepresentable {
    var name: Self.RawValue {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}

enum MyEnum: String, Eventable {
    case bla = "bla"
    case blu = "blu"

    static var all: [MyEnum] = [bla, blu]
}
```

For the second part of your question we need to configure the function to handle a generic type

I would suggest making the function generic as well here is an example

```
func printEnum<T: Eventable>(_ event: T) {
    print(event.name)
}
```

and we can use it for any object confirms to Eventable

```
printEnum(MyEnum.bla)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll give it a go :)